# Not able to get responce from the json url+iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I am requesting for the response which have alot of data in it.
But again and again my connection get lost.my internet is working properly.But still the connection get lost
The error :-Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

```
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
        if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
        appDel.Internet_connected=FALSE;
        [MainHandler performSelector:self.targetSelector_loseconenction];
        } 

(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //[connection release];
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    appDel.Internet_connected=TRUE;
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *valueToSave = responseString; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"responce"];
     NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"responce"]; 
     NSDictionary *result = [savedValue JSONValue];

}
```

Comment: What have you tried in terms of debugging the problem? Is the URL available in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

For Better controller with Networking, use this class:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.

If your connection is bad, you will need to handle this connection failed
with @try @catch @finally